# 過去のコミットメッセージの修正方法

Tags: git

たとえば3つ前のコミットメッセージを修正したいときに、

- git log
- git rebase -i コミットID
- r
- 書き換えて保存

としています。もっと手軽にやる方法はありますか？

Comment: 現状の手順からどんな点が改善できればよいでしょうか？`rebase`を使わず代わりとなる方法がないか？ということですか。

Comment: エディタが立ち上がってrに書き換えて、コミットメッセージを変更するのが面倒です。

Comment: コミットIDを確認する部分は手間ではないということでしょうか？　また、どういう風に修正できるのが理想ですか？

Comment: コミットIDを確認する作業も手間といえば手間なのですが、

Comment: いきなりコミットメッセージを書き換えたいのにそこまでたどり着くのに何プロセスも必要なのをなんとかしたいです。

Comment: なるほど、`git hoge <commit-id> -m "New Commit message"`みたいなことがしたい感じですね。

Comment: そうです。そして楽にできるならGUIでも構わないです

Answer (score 2):

`git rebase -i <commit-id>`するまでの省力化を考えてみました。
以下は`bash`が動く環境を前提としています。

```
git log --pretty=oneline | cat --number-nonblank; select id in $(git log --pretty=oneline | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=1); do git rebase -i "$id"; break; done
```

申し訳ないことにgitのaliasにする方法を見つけきれませんでしたが、関数としてbashrcに書いておくことはできました。

```
selrb() { 
    git log --pretty=oneline | cat --number-nonblank && select id in $(git log --pretty=oneline | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=1);
    do
        git rebase -i "$id";
        break;
    done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

直前のコミットであれば`git commit --amend`で直接コミットメッセージを編集出来ますが、2つ以上前のコミットメッセージを書き換えるには(既に使われている)`rebase`の手順しかないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

#### rewrite-history.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

refspec="$1"
export MSG="$2"
export REWRITE_REF=$(git log -n 1 --format=%H "$refspec" )
git filter-branch --msg-filter '
      if [ $GIT_COMMIT = $REWRITE_REF ]
      then
        printf "%s\n" "$MSG"
      else
        cat
      fi
    ' "$refspec"^..HEAD
```

#### 使い方

```
path/to/rewrite-history.sh master^3 "commit message"
```

#### 注意点

- filter-branch でゴリゴリコミットを書き換えていくので、書き換えた commit 移行、すべての sha がおきかわります。

Comment: `refspec`で指定したコミット以降のhashが全て書き変わることが注意点として回答内にあるとよいと思いました。

Comment: @伽語蓮弥 おっしゃるとおりなので、反映しました。